# formatStyle() for datatable in R Shiny not changing background color of row

Tags: r, shiny

I want to change the background color of every row in a datatable to be white. The code below has worked in the past but just recently stopped working. Instead of displaying a data frame with all white rows, it has alternating white/gray rows. How can I fix this issue?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("test")
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  output$test <- renderDataTable({
    df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(1,2,3))
    
    datatable(df) %>%
      formatStyle('x', target = 'row', backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable the shadow with parameter "stripe = FALSE":

```
  library(shiny)
  library(DT)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("test")
  )
  
  server <- function(session, input, output) {
    output$test <- renderDataTable({
      df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(1,2,3))
      
      datatable(df, class = list(stripe = FALSE)) %>%
        formatStyle('x', target = 'row', backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF")
        #formatStyle('x', target = 'row', backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow'))
      
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but now there's no borders between rows. I would like to keep the borders between rows

Comment: In that case, use class = "row-border" : `datatable(df, class = "row-border") %>%`